# Nonblocking simultaneous assignments to wires and registers in Verilog

Tags: verilog

I am interested to write Verilog module which simultaneously will update several outputs Something like following code, makes 3 operations at the same time (clk 10):

```
module mymodule (a,b,c,d,e);
input a;
input b;
output c;
output d;
output e;

wire b;
wire a;
wire c;
wire d;

reg e;

initial begin
c <=  #10  (a+b);
d <=  #10  a;
e  <= #10  b;
end

endmodule
```

Is that code legal?

Comment: what is the difference between using assign statements and just giving "=" ?

Comment: This was cross posted on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15381888/97073). OP wanted the assignment to happen after 10 (ten) timesteps.

Answer (score 4):

//**Not synthesizable** because of #delays can not be translated to something that is mapping wires.

```
reg clk ; //Rising edge every 10 timesteps
initial begin
  clk = 0;
  #5;
  forever begin
    #5 ;
    clk = ~clk;
  end
end
```

//**Synthesizable** because I have avoided use of a delay

```
reg [31:0] counter;
always @(posedge clk or negedge rst_n) begin
  if (~rst_n) begin
    counter <= 32'b0; // <-- reset value! assigned on negedge of reset
  else
    counter <= counter + 1;


always @(posedge clk or negedge rst_n) begin
  if (~rst_n) begin
    c <= 1'b0;
    d <= 1'b0;
    e <= 1'b0;
  end
  else if (counter == 10) begin
    c <=  (a+b);
    d <=   a;
    e <=   b;
    end
  end
endmodule
```

Comment: It would be helpful to OP to show how `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e` are declared.

Comment: @zhaba please give a bit more explanation and try to write an answer in such a way that it does not look like yelling.

Comment: @Zhaba we either write very similar code or this is a cleaned up version of my answer from [StackoverFlow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15383246/97073)

Answer (score 1):

No. `c`, `d`, and `e` should all be declared as `reg`s

Comment: will the assignment for c and d and e be done at clk = 10?

Comment: why should they be regs?I have additional module (nextmodule),which gets its input from wire c,if I declare c as reg  - how will I transfer the input to nextmodule from c?

Comment: You can take the value of a "reg" in exactly the same way as a wire. However, you have another bug: 'initial' means 'do this once at the start of the program'. #10 also means 'with a delay of 10 time units' not at clock pulse 10, and you don't have a clock anyway.

Comment: @pjc50: Was about to mention that. Don't confuse time units with clocks.